# Is height & width set to 0 when you element.hide() in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Would the jquery `.hide` method make the width and height 0 of div's and if I say show what will be height and width of div.

thanks

Comment: tricky question, although height and width aren't implicitly changed, try getting the dimensions from an element whose parent is hidden and browsers have problems

Answer (score 2):

`.hide()` its like adding a `display:none` into css. It does not affect the height or width of an item

Answer (score 2):

Nope, and it's easy to test:

http://jsfiddle.net/E9x2B/

HTML:

```
<div id="test1"></div>
<div id="test2">Testing</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test1 {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('div').hide();
console.log($('#test1').height());  //returns 40
console.log($('#test2').height());  //returns 20
```

Answer (score 0):

`.hide()` does not change the dimensions of the element. When you say `.show()` it will be the same size as it was before it was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery just sets `display:none` to hide the div.

Answer (score 0):

element.hide() simply alters the style to 'display: none'.  It doesn't do anything with the height and/or width.  See http://api.jquery.com/hide/ for more info.  Using element.show() will reset the 'display' style attribute to what it was before.

Answer (score 0):

`hide()` and `show()` store the `display` property and change between `display: none` and previously stored value. So, it doesn't change the `width` or `height` of an element.